# Регулярное выражение для .htaccess

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, .htaccess

Дано регулярное выражение для файла **.htaccess**: `( RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA])`, которое игнорирует все символы после `root` пути (`index.php` обработчик), как сделать так, чтобы не игнорировались`png` файлы и `css` файлы. Пытался вот так:  `^(.[^(png|css)])$`, не отрабатывает.

Comment: htaccess приведите сдесь полностью

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не силен в htaccess, но видел в одном движке такое

```
# если директория или файл существуют, использовать их напрямую
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: попробовал так, но изображения пропадают, ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA], блокирует все подключенные стили, js и картинки

Comment: хотя если поменять местами строки то все работает